# Showing that a set ordered by section is inductive

Tags: set-theory, upper-lower-bounds

I am dealing with a problem in Pinter set theory text.
This is the statement

Let A be a partially ordered set and let $\mathcal{A}$ be te set of all the well ordered subsets of A. For $C \in \mathcal{A}$ and $D \in \mathcal{A}$, defince $C<D$ if and only if C is a section of D.

The first problem is to show that $<$ is a partial order relation in $\mathcal{A}$ and I was successful with this.

However, the second one is proving that $\mathcal{A}$, ordered by $<$ is inductive, and I'm stuck on this.

I must show that every chain of A has an upper bound in $\mathcal{A}$.
For any chain $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$, I showed that $\cup \mathcal{C}$ is a least upper bound of $\mathcal{C}$, but I couldn't show that that this is an element of $\mathcal{A}$.

I believe that it is sufficient to show that every nonempty subset of $\cup \mathcal{C}$ has a least element, which implies that $\cup \mathcal{C}$ is well ordered so that this is an element of $\mathcal{A}$.

However, I couldn't prove that this has a least element. It just makes a vicious circle. How should I deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

To show that every subset of $\cup \mathcal{C}$ has a least element, we would like to work with the elements of $\mathcal{C}$ instead of $\cup \mathcal{C}$ itself, since we know that the elements of $\mathcal{C}$ are well-ordered. Let $S$ be a nonempty subset of $\cup \mathcal{C}$, and let $a \in S$. Then $a$ is an element of $C$ for some $C$ in $\mathcal{C}$. We know that $S \cap C$ is an initial segment of $S$, and so they share the same minimum element, if one exists. But since $C$ is well-ordered, this minimum element does exist!

The key part of this argument was being able to 'jump down' from $\cup \mathcal{C}$ to an element of $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: How can we make sure that $S \cap C $ has a minimum element? I'm not sure if this makes sense, because "for example if S = (0,1] and C = [0,1], C is a well ordered set, but $S \cap C$ does not have a minimum".

Comment: Are you saying that $C=[0, 1]$ is the closed interval on the real line from 0 to 1? Because this $C$ is certainly not well-ordered with the usual ordering on the reals (indeed, you gave a nonempty subset of $C$ that has no minimum element).

If $C$ is well-ordered (different $C$), then any subset of $C$ has a minimum element, and $S \cap C$ is certainly a subset of $C$!

Comment: I understand that $C \in \mathcal{C}$ has a minimum element, since $C \in \mathcal{A}$. However since we let S be a nonempty subset of $\cup \mathcal{C}$, how can we sure that S has a minimal element? If S does not have a minimal element, then $S \cap C$ doesn't necessarily have a minimal element although $C$ has a minimum.

Comment: Your definition of $\mathcal{A}$ consists of all *well-ordered* subsets of $A$, not just those subsets of $A$ that have a minimum element. Being well-ordered is a much stronger condition than having a minimum element. Perhaps a point of confusion is what you mean by "section" in your second paragraph. Could you define that for me?

Comment: in this book we define a section B of A to be a subset of B satisfying "If x is in A and there exists y in B such that x<=y, then x is in B" but anyway I think I understand what you mean. thanks

Comment: That's what I thought. What you call a "section" others call an "initial segment" when referring to well-ordered sets. Anyway, we know that the $C$ as stated in my answer is *well-ordered*, so *any subset* of $C$ has a minimum element. And $S \cap C$ is a subset of $C$, so $S \cap C$ has a minimum element, so $S$ has a minimum element (since $C$ comes from a chain).